# How to use a list field in django

Tags: python, django

lets say we have model which is an exam (am making an educational website),
and the exam has a list of people who have done it,
the question is what filed type should i use?

```
class Exam(models.Model):
difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=[('ez','easy'),('hrd', 'hard')])
module = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=[('math','math'),('physics', 'physics')])
completed_by = ???????????? (lets assume that there an other module callded user and i want this field to be a list of that users)
```

`

Comment: Did you referred ?   https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/list_fields.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is use a ForeignKey but on the other model (ie student or user).

ForeignKey creates a data releation of 1 to N,
meaning for 1 Exam you will have many Students.

Also, you should consider using ManyToManyField in order to enable students to do multiple exams. (N to N relation)

```
class Student(models.Model):
    # USER FIELDS
    exam - model.ForeignKeyField(Exam, related_name="completed_by")

class Exam(models.Model):
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=[('ez','easy'),('hrd', 'hard')])
    module = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=[('math','math'),('physics', 'physics')])

Exam.objects.all()[0].completed_by.all()  # Will return a list of students :)
```